# No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Token' from content with media type 'text/html'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting below error when I call a WebApi. This api was working fine till today morning.

The change we'd this morning was we move over production environment from Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 22012 R2. I think this is related to some server issue may be.

Please suggest.

Comment: where's the error?

Comment: I got this error when I call my webapi in my client application which in C#, believe me it was working before.

Comment: In IIS do you have `text/html` type added in MIME type?

Comment: Yes, I do and application/json also.